# How to keep my node js server alive

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I have created an app in `Node js` including with `express js` and I will execute the app using the command prompt

```
c:/myApp > npm start
```

And it is running my app, but whenever I closed the prompt the server is closing.I have tried with `forever` like

```
> npm install forever -g
> forever start --minUptime 1000 --spinSleepTime 1000 app.js
```

but it is not working either.Is there any way to keep the connection alive.Thanks in advance.

Comment: `forever` should do the trick actually. Please share your launch parameters

Comment: Because it is running in you prompt, don't close it. For something permanently running on a Windows server start it as a service.

Comment: @Eric can you please consider my edit

Comment: please try with -  forever start --minUptime 1000 --spinSleepTime 1000 ./bin/www

Comment: @Dineshaws actually I been in the app folder itself

Comment: @Gautam3164 go to parallel of app.js and run the command

Comment: @Dineshaws done the same thing..yet not working

Comment: @Gautam3164 any error you have seen?

Comment: @Dineshaws nope I did'nt get any

Comment: @Gautam3164 please show me content of /bin/www file

Comment: Since I'm using xampp my path was like c://xampp/htdocs/nodejs/myApp/

Answer (score 5):

I've used `forever` for about 3 years. It sucks. It has a ton of bugs and BS that hasn't been fixed after a long time.

I've switched to [pm2](http://pm2.keymetrics.io/). It has a much better CLI and API, and a lot less bugs.

CLI:

```
pm2 start app.js
```

API:

```
var pm2 = require('pm2')

pm2.connect(function(err) {
  pm2.start({
    script: 'runningTest.js'
  }, function(err, apps) {
    if(err) console.log(err)
    pm2.disconnect()
  })
})
```

Answer (score 0):

I use this instruction (Nginx + supervisord) for my projects in production:
http://cuppster.com/2011/05/12/diy-node-js-server-on-amazon-ec2/

Start read from chapter "Have Your Node Server Run Forever"

Comment: Dyrk I'm using windows